# How to generate log in service now when a browser is closed?

Tags: servicenow

I need to generate logs in service now whenever the   browser is closed or the session is expired. I tried using global business rule but couldnt achieve it. It will be greatfull if i can if i get an idea to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know how to generate a log and such in ServiceNow, and the problem you're having, is how to run code when the user closed their browser.

The best solution would probably be to create an onload client script which sets onbeforeunload to a function that triggers a log. 
More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

For the second part of your question, user sessions are tracked in a "user sessions" table. If you want to also log when theirs expires, you can do so with a business rule on that table.

Comment: I tried creating a client script for log  on browser  close howeevr from client script i can get alert but not a log in log table . I guess i have to handle this in server side scripting itself. For business rule on User Table i am getting while field will give me that the session is expired. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[GlideAjax](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GlideAjax#gsc.tab=0) to call from your client script to a server side script include.
Look at [GSLog](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GSLog#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var gl = new GSLog("com.snc.sla.tasksla.log", "TaskSLA");
```